# Setup helm for mu4e "jump to maildir"

Tags: helm, mu4e

In my mu4e setup, is there a way to have `helm` handle the "jump to maildir" list?

I am aware of the package `helm-mu` but it does not seem to have this functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try with `helm-comp-read` or `completing-read` in case `helm-mode` is turned on.

```
(let ((maildir (helm-comp-read "Maildir: " (mu4e-get-maildirs))))
  (mu4e-headers-search (format "maildir:\"%s\"" maildir)))
```

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else stumbles here looking for a way to make mu4e use `completing-read`, so it can be picked up by `helm-mode` (or `vertico-mode` in my case): instead of changing `mu4e~headers-jump-to-maildir` as in jagrg's answer, there is actually a variable for that:

```
(setq mu4e-completing-read-function 'completing-read)
; or (setq mu4e-completing-read-function 'helm-comp-read)
```

It was already introduced [in 2013](https://github.com/djcb/mu/commit/6e8e9ec44a994b840255d3ce32dc4b96c34b837e):

> New flexible method of customising completing-read
>
> Added the customisation option 'mu4e-completing-read-function' which
> can be used to choose which method of input-with-completion will be
> used by mu4e. This variable is set to the function which mu4e will
> use.
>
> By default, mu4e will use ido (via 'ido-completing-read'), but any
> compatible completing-read function can be used instead. Interesting
> choices would include 'helm-comp-read' for Helm-based completion, and
> 'completing-read' for the built-in basic completion system.